# in react file upload not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If you select any file its working perfectly but after selecting any file again if you click choose file button and not select any file then error occur "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')" how to resolve this error. I also gave filename===undefined but its not working

```js
import React from "react";
export default function DropDown() {
  const changeHandler = e => {
    let filename = e.target.files[0].name;
    let ext = filename.match(/\.([^\.]+)$/)[1];
    if (ext.includes("apk")) {
      document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "";
    } else if (typeof filename === undefined) {
      document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "only upload apk";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "only upload apk";
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input type="file" id="someId" accept=".apk" onChange={changeHandler} />
      <p id="para" style={{ color: "red" }}></p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple issues in your code. Please read on.

The first rule of React is do not mutate the DOM and you're clearly accessing DOM, which might mess up the rendering of React:

```js
if (ext.includes("apk")) {
  document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "";
} else if (typeof filename === undefined) {
  document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "only upload apk";
} else {
  document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "only upload apk";
}
```

Use a `useState()` hook and render it as per that. Solution:

```js
const [Para, setPara] = useState(null);
```

And your `if` statement will be:

```js
if (ext.includes("apk")) {
  setPara(null);
} else if (typeof filename === undefined) {
  setPara("only upload apk");
} else {
  setPara("only upload apk");
}
```

Finally, on the HTML / JSX side, you'll render as:

```js
{Para && <p>{Para}</p>}
```

The other issue is, you're checking the type with actual type. Consider this line:

```js
} else if (typeof filename === undefined) {
  setPara("only upload apk");
} else {
```

The `typeof` operator will always return only a string of the following:

[image: typeof output]

You're trying to equate these two, so you'll never get it right. Solution is:

```js
} else if (typeof filename === "undefined") {
  setPara("only upload apk");
} else {
```

For your original issue, you're trying to use `String.includes`. Instead, try using:

```js
if (ext.indexOf("apk") > -1) {
```

Potentially, this could be your solution:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function DropDown() {
  const [Para, setPara] = useState(null);
  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    if (e.target.files.length > 0) {
      let filename = e.target.files[0].name;
      let ext = filename.match(/\.([^\.]+)$/)[1];
      if (ext.indexOf("apk") > -1) {
        setPara(null);
      } else if (typeof filename === "undefined") {
        setPara("only upload apk");
      } else {
        setPara("only upload apk");
      }
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input type="file" id="someId" accept=".apk" onChange={changeHandler} />
      {Para && (
        <p id="para" style={{ color: "red" }}>
          {Para}
        </p>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: ScreenCast]

- **Preview & Demo:** https://pze2s.csb.app/
- **ScreenCast:** https://i.imgur.com/wu6LQTZ.mp4

Comment: thanks for give this suggestion sir , but when you select 1st time then again if you want to select the choose button and not selecting any file/close the file it throws again error

Comment: @SougataMukherjee Let me try.

Comment: @SougataMukherjee It works: https://i.imgur.com/wu6LQTZ.mp4 Please check once again after refreshing?

Comment: @SougataMukherjee On the `onChange` handler, I have added an extra if condition. Please check.

Comment: yes sir now its working fine